# Mercurial Hg Remote Operations Performance

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to compare the hg remote operation performance (pull, push, clone) using Mercurial 2.3 in Linux Red Hat and Windows using HTTP and SSH.  I think i could go ahead an write a script in ruby or something but i am too lazy to do it. Anyone know about any hg command to measure the cloning, pushing, pulling times?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `--time` to your `hg clone`, `hg push` and `hg pull` calls and Mercurial will tell you how much time the operation took.